# aql.literal is not a fucntion in arangoDB Foxx

Tags: javascript, arangodb, aql, foxx

I have a Foxx route like the following

```
 const aql = require('@arangodb').aql;

    route.get('ABC'){function(req,res){
    //Do some stuffs
    var AnArray1=req.queryParams.AnArray1||[DefaulArray]
    var AnArray2=req.queryParams.AnArray2||[DefaulArray]

    //Turn them into segment to put into AQL
 var segment=aql.literal(AnArray1.length>0 ? 'AND  u.Code IN '+ JSON.stringify(AnArray1)  : '');

    }
    .queryParam('AnArray1', joi.any())
    .queryParam('AnArray2', joi.any())
    .response(['json/application'], 'Done task')
```

This throw back an `aql.literal is not a function`. This is very strange to me since I thought it is a built-in.The version of arango is 3.3.5

Where did I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v3.3.5 is 8 months old (released 2018-03-28), `aql.literal` was added in v3.3.9 (2018-05-17):

- https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/pull/5219
- https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/blob/devel/CHANGELOG

An update to the latest 3.3 version (currently v3.3.17 from 2018-10-04) should fix the problem.

How you use `aql.literal()` doesn't look very safe in regards to `AnArray1`. There is no schema validation that would ensure that it's an array (`joi.any()`) and you don't test for the type at any later point. Strings would actually pass `req.queryParams.AnArray1||[DefaulArray]` and `AnArray1.length>0`, and you would end up with a query segment like `AND u.Code IN "some string"`, which will always be *false*.

The combination of `aql.literal()` and `JSON.stringify` is not recommended anymore. Starting with [ArangoJS version 6.7.0](https://github.com/arangodb/arangojs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#670---2018-10-24) and ArangoDB v3.4.0-RC.2 in Foxx, nesting of AQL template strings is supported:

```
var coll = db.collection('test')
var AnArray1 = [ "foo", 2, -0.1, true, null, [ false, { bar: true } ] ]

var segment = (
  Array.isArray(AnArray1) && AnArray1.length > 0
  ? aql`AND u.Code IN ${AnArray1}`
  : undefined
)
var fullQuery = aql`FOR u IN ${coll} FILTER u.attr == true ${segment} RETURN u`
```

This results in `fullQuery` being:

```
{
   query: 'FOR u IN @@value0 FILTER u.attr == true AND u.Code IN @value1 RETURN u',
   bindVars: {
     '@value0': 'test',
     value1: [ 'foo', 2, -0.1, true, null, [false, { bar: true } ] ]
   }
}
```

With `var AnArray1 = "foo"` you get this instead:

```
{
  query: 'FOR u IN @@value0 FILTER u.attr == true  RETURN u',
  bindVars: { '@value0': 'test' }
}
```

As long as you want to `AND` combine `FILTER` criteria my suggestion would be to use

```
aql`FILTER u.Code IN ${AnArray1}`
```

because you can then use this segment as filter on its own, whereas `AND ...` might not be valid in the full query (`FILTER AND ...`).